# Как решить 504 Nginx совместно с Apache при долгой работы скрипта?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, timeout, imagick

Есть Nginx с Apache (работают вместе). В Apache `max_execution_time=15`. В Nginx:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       20;
proxy_send_timeout          20;
proxy_read_timeout          20;
send_timeout                20;
keepalive_timeout           20;
```

Задач стоит такая:

> Есть много PDF файлов, которые надо конвертировать в JPG постранично.

Для каждого файла создается директория с его номером (равно названию), куда будут помещаться будущие JPG.

> Файл `123.pdf`. Директория .`/123/`. В ней будут `page-N.jpg`, где `N` номер страницы.

В PHP я использую Imagick для конвертации **PDF** в **JPG**. Мой скрипт получает `max_execution_time` и высчитывает на основе его сколько он может обработать страниц за время `max_execution_time`. Подсчет ведется на PDF файле из 1 страницы прогоном 100 раз или до момента наступления `max_execution_time`. У меня это **44 страницы**. Сейчас я имею 8 файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо пробежаться по этим файлам и конвертировать их в JPG. Опишу метод конвертации:

> Я беру начальную страницу из БД для конвертации и конечную (высчитываю). Далее с помощью Imagick делаю конвертацию.

```
public function convertFile($file, $start_page, $end_page, $write_folder)
{
    $file .= "[{$start_page}-{$end_page}]";
    $imagick = $this->imagickSetup($file);
    foreach ($imagick as $c => $_page) {
        $this->imagickPageSetup($_page, $start_page, $write_folder);
        $start_page++;
    }

    $imagick->clear();
    $imagick->destroy();

    return $start_page;
}
private function imagickSetup($file)
{
    $imagick = new Imagick($file);
    $imagick->setResolution(595, 842);
    $imagick->setImageFormat("jpg");
    $imagick->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(90);

    return $imagick;
}

private function imagickPageSetup($page, $c, $write_folder)
{
    $maxsize = 842;
    $page->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
    $page->adaptiveResizeImage($maxsize, $maxsize,true);

    $blank_page = new Imagick();
    $blank_page->newPseudoImage($page->getImageWidth(), $page->getImageHeight(), "canvas:white");
    $blank_page->compositeImage($page, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);
    $blank_page->writeImage("{$write_folder}page-$c.jpg");
    $blank_page->clear();
    $blank_page->destroy();
}
```

Все это находит в цикле `foreach` по каждому файлу. Проблема заключается в том, что мне Nginx выдает 504 по истечению 20 секунд. Как мне решить данную проблему?

Comment: Запускайте подобные задачи из консоли.

Comment: @zalex спасибо, проблема решена